# Call and return SQL function value in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database

I am using ASP.NET MVC, SQL database with model and entity. I wrote a SQL function in the database, and C# code in controller. I am trying to call a SQL function with C# and store SQL function returned int to C# int variable. And I have trouble time trying to work it.

I wrote the test code so when I know what to do, I can use this knowledge to resolve the problem I'm having.

I've tried researching, but none of the answers helped so far.

SQL Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunction(@Number INT)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@Number = 1)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 45
    END

    RETURN 20
END
```

C# code:

```
using (websiteDBEntities d = new websiteDBEntities())
{
    int check = d.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT dbo.TestFunction(1)");

    if (check == 45)
         return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}

return RedirectToAction("Action 2", "Controller");
```

I am trying to return either 20 or 45 depending on a parameter value.

So, is there a proper way to store a SQL function returned value to C# variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`d.Database.SqlQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) - it returns `IEnumerable` of result data set.
It seems that `ExecuteSqlCommand()` returns number of rows modified.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. It worked. I changed my code to:                                              var check = d.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT dbo.TestFunction(1)");                  
if(check.Sum() == 45)  return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");

Answer (score 0):

Your function in the second line says that the function returns a bit value and you are returning an int. You should change returns bit to returns int.

Comment: My bad, I meant Integer. I changed it.